# Why wordpress show me two version the same site

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using WordPress to build a site, but actually have a problem, the site don't update at all. For example, I update some data in a box, on pc can see the update, but in mobile don't.

Browser pc version

[image: pc]

Mobile version

[image: mobile]

**Update 1**

Searching a little more, I could find that typing the name of the page in google, and checking a little more, I could find that there is a cache that leaves the page hosted in google, the strange thing is that I am using Firefox.

[image]

**Update 2**

I prove the page in 5 browsers in the desktop and work fine.

- Firefox normal and developer edition
- Chrome
- Edge
- Opera
- Vivaldi

I do a search about the page on google, and see other problem. I was using a plugin for maintenance mode, and deactivate, and still appear the message as principal and not logo for the Google.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the cache on your mobile device? Furthermore you can investigate as to whether you have any cache plugins activated, or there may be server side caching? A little trick is view on your desktop, then using chrome, inspect the page and select mobile view. If the new page shows on the mobile view it's a good chance it's a caching problem.

Answer (score 0):

When working with `Wordpress` make sure use common browsers like Chrome and Opera. When your work isn't updating make sure you clear the cache of any caching plugin on the website and that of your browser(found in settings), if you are still in doubt then you can view the page on Incognito(`Ctrl + Shift + I`) for chrome on PC

Comment: For sure, I do all your recommendation, in 6 browsers, Chrome, Edge, Vivaldi, Firefox Developer edition, Normal Firefox and Opera, the result is good, the problem is maybe some plugin and google cache in the web console system.